# Как определить, что POST запросе передаются цифры?

Tags: php

Подскажите, как можно определить, что в POST запросе передается цифра?

Comment: размытая постановка задачи)
например, через функцию intval или с помощью регулярного выражения

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
$a = $_POST["a"];
if(is_int($a) || is_float($a))
{
//...
}
```

или так:

```
$a = $_POST["a"];
if(is_numeric($a))
{
//...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.